# Microsoft Graph Find meeting times add other attendees?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Find Meeting Times In Microsoft graph API have parameter name [attendees](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_findmeetingtimes)

if we have 1 attendees my code gonna look like this

```
{ 
  "attendees": [ 
    { 
      "type": "required",  
      "emailAddress": { 
        "name": "Fanny Downs",
        "address": "fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com" 
      } 
    }
  ],  
  "locationConstraint": { 
    "isRequired": "false",  
    "suggestLocation": "false",  
    "locations": [ 
      { 
        "resolveAvailability": "false",
        "displayName": "Conf room Hood" 
      } 
    ] 
  },  
  "timeConstraint": {
    "activityDomain":"unrestricted", 
    "timeslots": [ 
      { 
        "start": { 
          "dateTime": "2017-04-17T09:00:00",  
          "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time" 
        },  
        "end": { 
          "dateTime": "2017-04-19T17:00:00",  
          "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time" 
        } 
      } 
    ] 
  },  
  "meetingDuration": "PT2H",
  "returnSuggestionReasons": "true",
  "minimumAttendeePercentage": "100"
}
```

and i try to add more attendees by change code to this

```
"attendees": [ 
    { 
      "type": "required",  
      "emailAddress": { 
        "name": "Fanny Downs",
        "address": "fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com" 
      } ,
        "emailAddress": { 
        "name": "Joey medapple",
        "address": "joey@contoso.onmicrosoft.com" 
      } 
    }
  ]
```

but it's not working

how could i add other attendees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're placing the 2nd person at the wrong level. Each "attendee" should look contain both `type` and `emailAddress`:

```
"attendees": [{
    "type": "required", // First Attendee
    "emailAddress": {
        "name": "Fanny Downs",
        "address": "fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
}, {
    "type": "required", // Second Attendee
    "emailAddress": {
        "name": "Jonny Doe",
        "address": "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
}, {
    "type": "optional", // Third Attendee
    "emailAddress": {
        "name": "Dave Smith",
        "address": "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
}],
```

So you're complete request should look something like this:

```
{
    "attendees": [{
        "type": "required", // First Attendee
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Fanny Downs",
            "address": "fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "required", // Second Attendee
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Jonny Doe",
            "address": "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "optional", // Third Attendee
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Dave Smith",
            "address": "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
    }],
    "locationConstraint": {
        "isRequired": "false",
        "suggestLocation": "false",
        "locations": [{
            "resolveAvailability": "false",
            "displayName": "Conf room Hood"
        }]
    },
    "timeConstraint": {
        "activityDomain": "unrestricted",
        "timeslots": [{
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2017-04-17T09:00:00",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2017-04-19T17:00:00",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            }
        }]
    },
    "meetingDuration": "PT2H",
    "returnSuggestionReasons": "true",
    "minimumAttendeePercentage": "100"
}
```